# PHP Statement to SQL Case statement

Tags: php, sql

Can someone please help me interpret this code.  It was given to me by a Programmer and I can't figure out how to use it in my SQL query. I want to create a CASE statement in my SQL query with these conditions.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
for($i=0;$i<$dataCount;$i++) {
        $row = $data->data[$i];
        if($row->crefRefeeSignupId == null) {                       //so if the signup ID is null
            $return->data["open"]++;                                //the referral is open
        } else if($row->installScheduled == null) {                 //if the scheduled time is null
            $return->data["pending"]++;                             //it's pending an install
        } else if($row->installTicketResultId == null) {            //if the resolution is null
            $return->data["pending"]++;                             //it's also pending an install
        } else if(in_array($row->installTicketResultId, array(1, 2, 3, 46, 47, 48))) {  //if the ticket result ID is one of the 'success' ones
            $ninetyComplete = ($row->installScheduled + 2592000);   //how far out for the 90 days
            if(time() < $ninetyComplete) {                          //if we're not at 90-days complete
                $return->data["term"]++;                            //they're in their term
            } else if(in_array($row->crefReferCreditId,array(0,null)) || in_array($row->crefRefeeCreditId,array(0,null))) {
                $return->data["unCredited"]++;
            } else if(!in_array($row->crefReferCreditId,array(0,null)) || !in_array($row->crefRefeeCreditId,array(0,null))) {
                $return->data["credited"]++;
            } else {
                $return->data["pending"]++;
            }
        } else {                                                    //otherwise
            $return->data["cancelled"]++;                           //it's cancelled
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it. (Here's a good [Markdown Tutorial](https://commonmark.org/help/) as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at is a loop that aggregates different types of sign-ups. It's building up the counts of different sign-up statuses into an array like this:

```
$return->data = [
    'open' => 0,
    'pending' => 0,
    'term' => 0,
    'unCredited' => 0,
    'credited' => 0,
    'cancelled' => 0
];
```

Here are the conditions evaluated on each row in your table columns, with the resulting status:

```
if "crefRefeeSignupId" is NULL: open
else if "installScheduled" is NULL: pending
else if "installTicketResultId" is NULL: pending

else if "installTicketResultId" is IN (1, 2, 3, 46, 47, 48), then:
    if "installScheduled" < 90 days: term
    else if "crefReferCreditId" or "crefRefeeCreditId" is IN (0, NULL): unCredited
    else if "crefReferCreditId" or "crefRefeeCreditId" is NOT IN (0, NULL): credited
    else: pending

else: cancelled
```

The "translation" above should be clear enough to help you craft whatever SQL statements you may require. I'm not sure building up a monster CASE statement is the right way forward here. You may need to better define for yourself what information you actually need from your data-set.

Comment: Thanks a lot Markus!  This is exactly the help I needed.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. N.B. It seems to me that the last (nested) "pending" status will never happen, because `crefReferCreditId` will always either be in (0, NULL): unCredited, or not be in (0, NULL) (credited). We only have true and false, is/isn't, to work with here. There's no quantum option (after the values are exposed to an observer!).